# Allow only specific domains

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have an apache 2.4 server with some virtual hosts, let's say I have aaa.com domain and a few subdomains, bb.aaa.com and cc.aaa.com, currently I want apache server to listen only aaa.com and bb.aaa.com and ignore cc.aaa.com or just redirect cc.aaa.com to aaa.com (btw I have no virtual host for cc.aaa.com).

So my objective would be to allow connections only from aaa.com and bb.aaa.com, any other connection (from direct IP or any other subdomain not handled by virtual hosts) should be redirected to aaa.com or just refused.

I did not found any solution for this, actually I am not even sure if it's possible.

Comment: I would look into setting up two virtual hosts, one for your main site, and then one for everything that should redirect. In the redirect host, setup `RewriteRule`s to redirect to one of the main sites.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a virtual host for cc.aaa.com and if this domain is pointing to your server then by default apache will enter into the first virtual host. So you might want to set the redirect here.

Comment: Hi, that is what I am looking for, however I am experiencing an issue, I used this tutorial [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-centos-7) to create Virtual Hosts and currently I have 3 Virtual Hosts, for example I have domain.com, a.domain.com and b.domain.com, I would like that every address not listed on Virtual Hosts files to redirect to domain.com but by the default they are going to a.domain.com and I don't know how to change it, is there a way to tell apache which Virtual Host should be the first?

Comment: You can rearrange the virtual hosts to tell apache which one it should enter as default.  

Or use the below redirect rule in your first virtual host.

    `RewriteCond     %{HTTP_HOST} ^!(www\.)?example.com`  

    `RewriteRule     ^/(.*)$ http://example2.com/ [NC,NE,L,R=301]`